# How to filter a JavaScript object based on child object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have an array of objects with an array that contains other objects. I'm trying to work out how I can filter the first objects based on data inside the array of second objects

```
[{
   object1Name: "test",
   secondaryObjects: [
    {
       second2Name: "test-again"
       data: "hello"
    },
    {
       second2Name: "Hello!"
       data: "remove based on this"
    }
   ]
},
{
  another object...
}]
```

I want to filter the first array by checking if any objects contain a secondary object with the data "hello". If they have a secondary object with that data it then filters out the object1

```
const filteredField = data.filter((entry) => {
            return entry.secondaryObjects[0].second2Name.includes('hello')
        })
```

When I use this, I have it working but it only checks the first index of secondary objects but if it's in index 1 it does not work.

Comment: Just use `some` (i.e., `return entry.secondaryObjects.some((so) => so.second2Name.includes("hello"));`)

Comment: If you think about it, this is just a multi-step filter. You use `some` because you don't care about the array being returned from the inner filter, rather you just care that it isn't empty and can therefore stop looking sooner.

Comment: I see so does I was trying to .map through it and wasnt understanding why it was working but that makes more sense now! didnt realise .some was a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you just need to check any inner object contains your desire data by using [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?retiredLocale=de)

```js
const data = [{ object1Name: "test", secondaryObjects: [{ second2Name: "Hello!", data: "remove based on this" }, { second2Name: "hello", data: "hello" } ] }, { object1Name: "test", secondaryObjects: [{ second2Name: "test-again", data: "test...." }] } ];
const filtered = data.filter(item => item.secondaryObjects.some(it => it.second2Name === "hello"));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into all secondary objects then. `Some` will do that for you:

```
const filteredField = 
  data.filter(entry => entry.secondaryObjects
    .some(o => o.second2Name.includes('hello'))
```